Passing a parameter with a space to a Perl program in a Window's batch file
I have a following batch file:
@echo off
set GENDER_LIST=M F
set AGE_GROUP_LIST="[20, 30)" "[30, 40)"

for %%G in (%GENDER_LIST%)    do (
    for %%A in (%AGE_GROUP_LIST%) do (
        perl argvSample.pl "%%G %%A"
        echo ---------------
    )
)

and a following Perl program:
use strict;

print "\"".join("\", \"", @ARGV)."\"\n";

Running the batch results in the following unexpected output:
"M [20,", "30)"
---------------
"M [30,", "40)"
---------------
"F [20,", "30)"
---------------
"F [30,", "40)"
---------------

I want it to output the following:
"M [20, 30)"
---------------
"M [30, 40)"
---------------
"F [20, 30)"
---------------
"F [30, 40)"
---------------

How should I fix the batch file to get the desired output?

Scrap the batch file and do the whole thing in perl.

If you're going to write a script in Windows, at least use PowerShell.

Replace the entire posted batch file by the single command line: @for %%I in (M F) do @for %%J in ("[20, 30)" "[30, 40)") do @perl.exe "%~dp0argvSample.pl" "%%G %%~J" & echo --------------- That's it. It would be best that perl.exe is referenced with its fully qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) enclosed in " if the Perl executable path contains a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~. That would avoid lots of file system accesses during batch file execution by cmd.exe searching otherwise for perl.exe in folders of environment variable PATH.

Run in a command prompt window for /? to get output the usage help of the Windows command FOR on several pages explaining that %~I or %%~I as needed in a batch file references the string assigned to the loop variable I (or J in the command line above) with surrounding " removed. There is also a Microsoft online documentation for FOR (see link) and FOR can be found also in A-Z index of Windows CMD commands.

The unconditional command operator & is explained in my answer on single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file. It just means that independent with which exit code first run perl.exe exited, cmd.exe should run next also the command echo on each of the in total four loop iterations.

Regardless of the answer below I would like to understand why you have all the arguments enclosed in one set of quotes.  Every scripting language or utility I have ever used from the command line I have never seen all the arguments grouped into one set of quotes.  I would normally see script_language script_name "arg1" "arg2" I do have a perl programmer in my group and I am pretty sure I have seen him do it this way as well.

@Squashman My problem still would have been illustrated with just %%A part. Sorry for the confusion. As for your question, I made a bad design decision where all options are placed as a single argument in the middle of a fixed number of arguments: e.g. perl XXX.pl inputPath optionString outputPath.  For a simple script (where you thought you were just going to use it once), fixed number of arguments is fine I guess but maybe put the option (switch) at the beginning or at the end so that it can easily be changed to a variable number of arguments.

continuing from above I guess that is how things are most of the time: program lives longer than the auhtor's intention.

"%%G %%A"

produces
"F "[30, 40)""

Replace it with
"%%~G %%~A"

See output of help for.

echo "%%G %%A" did produce what you mentioned above of "F "[30, 40)"". Changing it to "%%~G %%~A" for both echo and as a Perl program's argument gave me the desired output. Thanks.
